# How to create a scala based service daemon which can be called by a web app?

Tags: scala

How could I write a service in scala such that a web application would be able to call out to its endpoints?

How would it run as a daemon?

Comment: I meant a web application in say Ruby or Python, to make calls out to a service endpoint or something written in scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Lift to build a REST-style web service. The [Lift wiki](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/REST_Web_Services) explains it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [BlueEyes](https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes/blob/master/README.md) and [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/) if all you want is an efficient/scalable RESTful service, without the extra bells and whistles that Lift gives you.